# Mocking a browser in a continuous server process

Tags: javascript

We are working with a provider that provides access to a dataset only through a JS/websocket interface (ie: no direct API).  I'd like to essentially keep a virtual 'browser window' open on the server and load my client js there, so we can actively broadcast the data feed back to our servers through AJAX.

I've been unable to find anything that would allow us to run js as an active process; I would appreciate any pointers the community could provide.

Comment: A bit unorthodox but perhaps a Windows Service with WebBrowser control?

Comment: AJAX is simply a mechanism for sending HTTP requests to an end point. Are you sure you need a Javascript solution here?

Comment: Do you mean you want the server to make the Js requests to the provider? Or do you want these calls to be done on the client but making calls to the provider directly?

Answer (score 2):

You could use node.js or phantomjs.

Comment: phantomjs would load the page (and thereby run any JS) but I believe it doesn't run as a process- i want to have a JS client connect to the data feed service through a web socket and actively consume the data feed.  Is this assumption wrong? (ie: is there a way to keep the page 'live'?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)? Based on the [examples](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start) it should be fairly simple to load, parse and save arbitrary JS from the DOM.